# OSGI is it possible to have 2 persistence units in 1 bundle

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, apache-servicemix

As the title states, is it possible to have 2 `persistence units` in 1 `bundle`, and therefore two `EntiManagers`

In OSGI, a `persistence bundle` has the following in its `pom.xml` file :

```
<Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
```

where `persistence.xml` defines the `persistence unit`

So if it is possible:

- what is the syntax to define 2 instead ?
- in my case, the persistence provider is hibernate, would that cause a problem ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the OSGi JPA Specification allows for the `Meta-Persistence` header to be specified as a comma-separated list of resources. You can read full details in section 127.4.2 ("Meta Persistence Header") of the OSGi Compendium Release 6 Specification.

You also asked if Hibernate presents a problem. It should not, so long as the JPA Provider implementation you are using is compliant with the OSGi JPA Specification.